# c++ Visual Studio, 'vc_attributes::YesNoMaybe' : 'enum' type redefinition error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to get the memory space of a process using the following c++ code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>

void PrintMemoryInfo( DWORD processID )
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;

    // Print the process identifier.

    printf( "\nProcess ID: %u\n", processID );

    // Print information about the memory usage of the process.

    hProcess = OpenProcess(  PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                             PROCESS_VM_READ,
                             FALSE, 
                             processID );
    if (NULL == hProcess)
        return;

    if ( GetProcessMemoryInfo( hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc)) )
    {
        printf( "\tPageFaultCount: 0x%08X\n", pmc.PageFaultCount );
        printf( "\tYour app's PEAK MEMORY CONSUMPTION: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.PeakWorkingSetSize );
        printf( "\tYour app's CURRENT MEMORY CONSUMPTION: 0x%08X\n", pmc.WorkingSetSize );
        printf( "\tQuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage );
        printf( "\tQuotaPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage );
        printf( "\tQuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage );
        printf( "\tQuotaNonPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage );
        printf( "\tPagefileUsage: 0x%08X\n", pmc.PagefileUsage ); 
        printf( "\tPeakPagefileUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.PeakPagefileUsage );
    }

    CloseHandle( hProcess );
}

int main( )
{
  PrintMemoryInfo( GetCurrentProcessId() );

    return 0;
}
```

but got errors like

```
Error   2   error C2011: 'vc_attributes::YesNoMaybe' : 'enum' type redefinition 
Error   3   error C2011: 'vc_attributes::AccessType' : 'enum' type redefinition 
Error   4   error C2011: 'vc_attributes::Pre' : 'struct' type redefinition  
Error   5   error C3094: 'repeatable': anonymous usage not allowed  
...
```

How to solve that, I am using visual studio 2008

Comment: For some reason the #pragma once in vc/include/sourceannotations.h header file isn't working.  Hard to guess why, make sure you didn't accidentally change the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cleaning and rebuilding the entire solution. There are a few reports with the similar error, like [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvc/thread/fb887af6-45dc-42b9-94bb-ab4d08a16dd8), with the apparent solution being a rebuild.